# Finding a pattern in a Numeric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, programming

The following script generates a vector of integers and plots its items (index vs value).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_list = [0, 1]; n = 262000;
for i in range(1, n): num_list.append(num_list[i]); num_list.append(num_list[i]+num_list[i+1]);
plt.plot(range(2*n), num_list, "ko", markersize=1); plt.xscale('log'); plt.yscale('log');
plt.show()
```

---

Starting with the vector `[0, 1]` and `i=1`, we append the $i^{th}$ value to the vector, then append the sum of that item and its successor. Shortly, a pattern emerges:

```
[0, 1] -> [0, 1, 1, 2] -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3] -> ... -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1]
```

Notice that the number $1$ (and every other number) appears in positions that are increasing powers of two starting from its previous occurrence. Here is the respective plot (with decimal logarithm axes):

[image: Relevant code]

[image: Relevant plot]

---

**My question is**: why does this sequence exhibits a fractal-like behavior? Why does the occurrence frequency decreases geometrically for every number? Any insight about its properties will surely be appreciated.

Comment: [Here](http://oeis.org/A002487) is a bunch of information on your sequence.

Comment: Thank you! Knowing the recurrence equation for the n-th term, it seems viable to prove the "geometric spacing" by induction. I will read more about it and eventually try to post an intuitive explanation.